# PostgreSQL queries without using joins

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to write/make a schema for a PostgreSQL db and then query let's say

```
SELECT email, username, city_population
FROM users, cities
WHERE email = 'user@example.com'
```

And the connection between the users table and cities table is defined somewhere else, and PostgreSQL uses that informtion to join the tables. Is there something like that?

Edit: and without views

Comment: The kind of automatic reference-finding you want is implemented by some query generators and ORMs, but not natively in SQL. What problem are you trying to solve with this? What's the underlying reason?

Comment: @CraigRinger, I'm joining few tables. Nothing special. I thought that because let's say city_id in users_table always refers to city_id in cities_table why should I need to define it in all my queries? unnecessary. that's what I have thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `NATURAL JOIN` described by Daniel is as close as SQL comes. There is a reason. While people often want to join based on equality of columns in the same domain, they sometimes want something more complex. I have seen a lot of queries which ask for things like "Who lives in a city within 300 miles of this city?", "What are the 3 closest cities to this user, excluding the one they live in?", or "What other users live in the same state as this user?" Having automatic joins based on some assumed join criteria would make it harder to write unambiguous queries to answer questions like that.

That said, it is not uncommon to want what you're looking for, so as Craig said, there are many tools which use foreign key definitions to provide default linkages.

Based on the question, I suspect that you might possibly be interested in [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/), which provides automated linking and other convenience features to assist in bridging the gap between a relational database and other formats which people might already know. Its development is funded in part by foundation grants, including the National Science Foundation. (I have no relationship to the project other than having read documentation, and having had a brief conversation with one of the authors at a conference.)

Answer (score 4):

There is `NATURAL JOIN`, but for that to work the columns have to have the same name. In other words, this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE cities (
  city_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  city_population INTEGER,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
  city_id INTEGER REFERENCES cities,
  ...
);

SELECT email, username, city_population
FROM users
NATURAL JOIN cities
WHERE email = 'user@example.com';
```

Will's view solution is nicer and probably closer to what you should want, but I think this is closer to the letter of your question.

Comment: I want to join them in something like 'schema'. And the db will look at it and find its path all to the way to the latest table. is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what it is you mean, but I suspect it's not something databases can do. They cannot, for instance, guess which tables you mean to involve by implication.

Answer (score 2):

So you want results from the joint tables, just without defining how to join them?

The answer is NO. Obviously, you have to join them *somehow* and since there are many possible ways, you have to define *how*.

[`NATURAL JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) might be the next best thing to what you are talking about. See [@Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669129/939860) for that.

Another syntactical shortcut in standard SQL is the [`USING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM). With it you can define a list of columns on which to join tables. Column names have to be *unique* on both sides.

```
SELECT u.email, u.username, c.city_population
FROM   users  u 
JOIN   cities c USING (city_id)
WHERE  u.email = 'user@example.com'
```

I also added *table qualification* to your otherwise potentially ambiguous query.